# How to have an activity with single instance in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using this flag in `manifest.xml` to have only one instance of the activity.

`android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

But if this activity say A launches a new activity say B and then pressing back button on B not showing activity A. It is showing activity from where we launched A.

Basically i want to create a activity if it is not in stack and if in stack bring on the top. But back button should also work properly.

What flag i should use for this.

Comment: Make noHIstory flag in manifest for activities which you dont want to see.

Comment: android:launchMode="singleTask"

Answer (score 1):

use 
android:launchMode="singleTask" 
instead of 
android:launchMode="singleInstance"

Answer (score 0):

following code activityA(parent activity),then A launch activity b. Declare these lines in manifest.xml file. When click back button it goes to previous activity(i.e A(parent)).

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityB"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName=".ActivityA"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.prathap.ActivityA" />
    </activity>
```